# How to filter out SQL Select without using "where" condition?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014-express

I would like to give a specific permission to user. Example; A user cannot see Software department from Department column in the Personnel table. So when I execute "Select * from Personnel" it will automatically filter out the Software department without using where condition. Is this possible ?

Comment: That's called [row-level security](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security). There's native support in SQL Server 2016; in earlier versions you had to roll your own.

Comment: You can also create a view with your filter and grant access to that view only.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to create a view for the user and give them permission to the view, but not the table.